# .bash_profile not working

Tags: command-line, bash, macosx

I'm trying to set AVARIABLE in my bash_profile:

```
echo export "AVARIABLE=example" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After that, AVARIABLE should be working, but...

```
bash: AVARIABLE: command not found
```

What in the hell could be causing this?

Comment: is `AVARIABLE` some kind of alias?

Comment: *"After that, AVARIABLE should be working"* yes - but only in the sense that `echo $AVARIABLE` outputs the value `example`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What's with the "macosx" tag? Are you not using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To reference an environment variable, you'd need to preface it with `$` : `$AVARIABLE`